# Elastic Beanstalk Django migrations not working

Tags: python, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, django-migrations

I've made a `.ebextensions/02_python.config` file:

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py migrate --noinput"
    leader_only: true
  02_createsu:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py createsu"
    leader_only: true
  03_collectstatic:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
```

But when I run `eb deploy`, it throws me the following error:

```
Creating application version archive "app-8987-200210_133822".
Uploading vspmfinal/app-8987-200210_133822.zip to S3. This may take a while.
Upload Complete.
2020-02-10 08:08:27    INFO    Environment update is starting.
2020-02-10 08:08:52    INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
2020-02-10 08:09:03    ERROR   [Instance: i-0ba93a0edfd159030] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...ack(traceback) from exc_value
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "accounts_user" does not exist.
container_command 01_migrate in .ebextensions/02_python.config failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
2020-02-10 08:09:03    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2020-02-10 08:09:03    ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0ba93a0edfd159030'. Aborting the operation.
2020-02-10 08:09:03    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.
```

My app name is accounts. I've created my own user class by overriding Django's user class. What am I doing wrong? Why is the migration not working? I'm creating this application for the first time.

Answer (score 3):

Resolved this issue by running makemigrations locally then committing migrations folder.

Comment: Is it possible to put your database configuration in `settings.py`, the `PostgreSQL` package installed in your virtual environment and the `.ebextensions` files? I still got the issue. The official configuration doesn't work at all. And this virtual environment path here `/opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate` does not exist in my EC2 instance.